# error TS2307: Cannot find module 'vectormap-data/world.js'

Tags: angular, angular-seed, devextreme-angular

I am using devextreme maps, Here I have to integrate those into my angular-seed app.

But I am getting the error,

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'vectormap-data/world.js'
```

I made all configurations But still getting that error.

Please help me on this.

Thank You

Comment: have you installed all the dependencies?

Comment: Yes @PardeepJain
my config with devextreme ->
'devextreme': 'node_modules/devextreme',
'vectormap-data': 'node_modules/devextreme/dist/js/vectormap-data',
'devextreme-angular': 'node_modules/devextreme-angular'

Comment: Try the solution from the following thread: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T639448/vectormap-the-ts2307-cannot-find-module-vectormap-data-world-js-error-occurs-on-an